# AngularJS : ng-repeat (return single value)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, angularjs-ng-repeat

Yo everyone !
I've got :

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in list">
.....<td>{{x.Name}}</td>
```

and the view is :

```
a
a
a
a
```

For the time being, all is right.
But I would like that the table returns me the value only one time if "Name" is already present in this table. What I need is this view :

```
a
```

Because "Name" owns many "a" value.

I hope I'm accurate enough about my problem because I'm new to AngularJS.
Thank you.

**EDIT1** : my controller view :
    myApplicationModule.controller('controllertable', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $routeParams) 
    {
        $scope.list = list;
    }]);

which refers to a file .json:

```
var list = [
{
    ...
    "Name" = "a",
    ...
}
```

Comment: How does your controller look like? Why don't you make on controller side sure, that every name is just one time present in x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Create the following filter

```
app.filter('unique', function() {
     return function(list, keyname) {
      var output = [], 
          keys = [];

      angular.forEach(list, function(item) {
          var key = item[keyname];
          if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
              keys.push(key);
              output.push(item);
          }
      });

      return output;
   };
});
```

And use it like

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in list | unique: 'name'">
    <td>{{x.name}}</td>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register a custom filter.

```
angular.module('yourApp.filters', [])
    .filter('distinct', function() {
        return function (list) {
            var distinctList = new Array();
            var j = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                var x = list[i];
                if (! containsName(distinctList, x.Name)) {
                    distinctList[j] = list[i];
                    j++;
                }
            }
            return distinctList;
        }
    });

function containsName(list, name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].Name == name) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In your controller you add the array list to the $scope:

```
yourAppControllers.controller('YourCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list = [
        {
            Name: 'A',
            email: 'a1@example.com'
        },
        {
            Name: 'B',
            email: 'b@example.com'
        },
        {
            Name: 'A',
            email: 'a2@example.com'
        },
        {
            Name: 'C',
            email: 'cc@example.com'
        }
    ];
}]);
```

In the ng-repeat statement now simply write:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in list | distinct">
         <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So, thank you for your answer.

I added the custom filter on the top of my controller.js.
The array list in the $scope is still the same `$scope.list = list` which refers to .json file and I just deleted `$routeParams` from my original writing. Finally I added `| distinct` at the end of the ng-repeat and all my data disappeared :/